# Three.js - Updating texture on plane

Tags: three.js, textures, auto-update

I'm trying to make a terrain editor. So I have a plane with multiple materials on it, which I initialize like so:

```
var materials = [];
var grasstexture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('Img/grass.png', {}, function() { });
var rocktexture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('Img/rock.png', {}, function() { });
materials.push(new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0xffffff, map: grasstexture}));
materials.push(new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0xffffff, map: rocktexture}));
// Plane

this.geometry.materials = materials;
for(var i = 0; i <  this.geometry.faces.length; i++)
{
    this.geometry.faces[i].materialIndex = 0;
}

this.geometry.dynamic = true;
this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh( this.geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(  ) );
this.mesh.receiveShadow = true;
```

The result is a square plane stripped with the two textures.

Now, I can't seem to update the materialIndex for each vertex during the runtime. I have tried:

```
face.materialIndex = 1;

for(var i = 0; i < geo.materials.length; i++){
    geo.materials[i].needsUpdate = true;
}

for(var i = 0; i <  this.geometry.faces.length; i++)
{
    geo.faces[i].materialIndex = 0;
}

for(var i = 0; i < geo.materials.length; i++){
    geo.materials[i].needsUpdate = true;
}
this.mesh.needsUpdate = true;
this.mesh.material.needsUpdate = true;

geo.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
geo.normalsNeedUpdate = true;
geo.colorsNeedUpdate = true;

geo.computeFaceNormals();
geo.computeVertexNormals();

geo.computeCentroids();
geo.computeTangents() ;
```

And every other 'materialIndex' and 'needsUpdate' variable in Three.js I was able to find, but still nothing happens. How do I force an update on the material indices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. `materialIndex` is only used in the first render to partition the geometry into chunks, with each chunk having the same material. Also, you cannot re-partition the chunks.

What you can do, however, is change a material in the `materials` array.

```
materials[ 0 ] = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();
```

You do not need to set any `needsUpdate` flags to `true` after doing so, either.

An alternate thing you can do is give each face it's own material from the start, and then, for example, just change a material's texture.

```
mesh.geometry.materials[ 0 ].map = texture;
texture.needsUpdate = true;
```

Comment: Problem is that after giving each face its own texture, you can imagine how slow it is to render a 500x500 vertex terrain :S Is there a better way to change the texture applied to each vertex? Ideally, there would also be smooth blending between textures.